# Subclassing property group class problem

Tags: python, scripting

This code throws AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute 'x', what might be the cause?

```
class A (bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    x : bpy.props.StringProperty(name = "X")

class B (A):
    ind : bpy.props.IntProperty(name = "Prop")

bpy.utils.register_class(A)
bpy.utils.register_class(B)

bpy.types.Scene.testvalue = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=B)
print(bpy.context.scene.testvalue.x)

bpy.utils.unregister_class(A)
bpy.utils.unregister_class(B)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Only use `bpy.types.PropertyGroup` for the registered class type.**

The property group and `bpy.props` properties are wired up as properties through the "*rna voodoo magic*" internally with blender when registered.

Similarly as often seen with operators and [panels](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Panel.html#mix-in-classes), only give the registered class the type you are registering. *For want of a more technical description.  Refered to as "Mix in classes" in panel link*

eg below the `B` propertygroup class inherits `A`.  All annotations of `B` and `A` become properties of the pointer property instance..

```
import bpy

class A ():
    x : bpy.props.StringProperty(name = "X", default="Foo")

class B (A, bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    ind : bpy.props.IntProperty(name = "Prop")

#bpy.utils.register_class(A)
bpy.utils.register_class(B)

bpy.types.Scene.testvalue = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=B)
print(bpy.context.scene.testvalue.x)

#bpy.utils.unregister_class(A)
bpy.utils.unregister_class(B)
```

Prints "Foo" to the system console.